# How to make local rails app respond to errors like heroku does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

If you push code to heroku, and there is an error anywhere in your site code---the site will crash.  However, locally you will only experience this error if you land on the page or methods that contains the error.  Is there a rails setting that will cause the the local site to respond to errors that exist anywhere in the entire site code---like heroku does?

Comment: I have never seen heroku crash everywhere before, but what I would suggest is putting 2 apps in heroku, a staging and prod app, test your code on staging and catch errors before you push to prod, you can also run your application in production mode locally

Comment: Ya, I need to set up a staging environment.  And, just for the sake of doing it---I'll try production mode locally.  Thanks.

Comment: good luck with that if not let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local)? I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for. And I couldn't get it to go. But, thought I would mention it.